# Rcpp compile error

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to run a test function but I am getting a compile error:

```
library(Rcpp)  
library(inline) 

testfun = cxxfunction(  
signature(x="numeric", i="integer"),  
body = '  
NumericVector xx(x);    
int ii = as<int>(i);  
xx = xx * ii;  
return( xx );  
', plugin="Rcpp")  
testfun(1:5, 3)
```

Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! 
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB filede44a566900.cpp 2> filede44a566900.cpp.err.txt' had status 1

I would be grateful for your help. I am using windows 7, R2.15.1, 64 bit

Comment: are you using cygwin? check that it is configured correctly? what compiler version is used? i had similar problems before as a result of linkage errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `verbose=TRUE` as you seem to have a simple setup issue -- maybe your PATH is not correct.

Your code is correct and runs just fine here under Linux (where no additional gymnastics is needed as there is on Windows).

Your slightly edited / indented example as copied from my Emacs ESS buffer:

```
R> library(inline)
R> 
R> testfun <- cxxfunction(signature(x="numeric", i="integer"), body = '
+    NumericVector xx(x);
+    int ii = as<int>(i);
+    xx = xx * ii;
+    return( xx );
+ ', plugin="Rcpp")
R> 
R> testfun(1:5, 3)
[1]  3  6  9 12 15
R>
```

Comment: Note that Cygwin is not supported.